# Design Issue: How to design a webpage that should show 11 elements with a description for each elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am developing a website and as a part of this website to design a webpage just for showing 11 elements which about the principals of the company. Each one of these elements has a long description. The website design is as following: menu bar with logo at the top, side bar at the left and body at the right.

At the beginning, I was thinking to list the elements on the side bar and the description of each elements will be appeared on the right when the user clicks on a specific element (using javascript), but later on the customers don't like this design and they said it will confuse the user since he will need to scroll down for reading a long description for just one element and then scroll up to select another element. Besides that, how will the user know the flow of navigation of this webpage? which means that the elements on the left and when he clicks on one of them, he will see the description on the right?

So how should I design this page? please tell me if I should use specific css layout or javascript or jquery plugin (mention the name of the plugin if it is possible)

Comment: You could have the sidebar follow the user if they scroll down. Although i personally find this annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, you can play with the basic principle [on this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PajFP/4/). Playing with "position: fixed", float and negative margins does the trick.

Then you can look [at this page](http://blog.html.it/layoutgala/) for plenty examples.

But your best bet is to use any decent jquery menu plugin, they all all provide this functionality. just google "jquery menu" or "css fixed menu", or a mix to have **tons** of choices.

Answer (score 0):

For javascript libray, use jquery itself.
The 11 elements that you are referring can be displayed in the following way:

```
         . **Principal 1**
                Description of Prinicipal 1
           **Principal 2**
                Description of Prinicipal 2
```

Initially only the div's containing Prinicipal1, Principal 2 etc. will be shown to the user. The description of each prinicipals will be hidden.

When the user clicks on the title of Prinicpal1, display corresponding description.
Use $("<>").show('slow); And if the description is already in expanded state, the user can click on the principal again to hide it.

This will be a very good experience
Let me know if you have any further doubts